# Redirecting to home page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-part

I have a page containing webparts. When I try to enter some data, it sometimes redirects to home page!

This happens even if nothing specific happens i.e. just clicking on the Button may cause this error. This is not happening all the time. Any idea about the cause?

EDIT

I have two webparts in that page. Both are connected too. One webpart contains the filters and the other webpart will show the data based on these filters. Now, sometimes I'm getting error even when I click the link to this page. Sometimes it will happen only if I click the Search button. My page name is announcements.aspx. See the ULS error message I'm getting.

```
Orphaning WebPart with id g_76cd0982_9a0c_418c_a50b_0154a1b99981 on Page    http://esiadsspdplot2:4444/Pages/home.aspx?ReturnUrl=/Pages/PageNotFoundError.aspx?requestUrl=http://esiadsspdplot2:4444/Pages/announcements.aspx&requestUrl=http://esiadsspdplot2:4444/Pages/announcements.aspx.
```

Comment: could you post your uls error specific to that page, edit your question and add it in, i did see it in your comment but its not that readable!

Comment: Done. Please check now.

Answer (score 1):

sounds like there is an issue with the webparts and the database!

check on central administration health analyzer to see if it popus up?

also completely remove both webparts and add them back in, before you add them back in do an iisreset! then see if the problem has gone!

looks like sharepoint is orphaning your webpart with id: `g_76cd0982_9a0c_418c_a50b_0154a1b99981`  and is returning you to `http://esiadsspdplot2:4444/Pages/home.aspx` even tho your on `http://esiadsspdplot2:4444/Pages/announcements.aspx` as its comming up with an error that triggers `ReturnUrl=/Pages/PageNotFoundError.aspx` that throws you back to the home page! I belive the webpart is being corrupt somehow! like i said totally remove it and add them back in from scratch and hopefully they wont be orphaned!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried that. But, still the same error! I have seen in the Central Admin that there are some critical issues showing there. Not sure whether they are related to this or not.

Answer (score 0):

Are you the original author of the page? If not,have you checked if the original author created custom script on the page?

> I meant to add this as a comment but I'm not yet allowed to /sad

Comment: Yes. I'm the original author.. One thing is, I have two webparts in this page which is connected. . In ULS logs, not much info was there... See this msg.. Orphaning WebPart with id g_76cd0982_9a0c_418c_a50b_0154a1b99981 on Page esiadsspdplot2:4444/Pages/home.aspx?ReturnUrl=/Pages/…. Any idea about this error ?

Comment: Does the error occur in the first or the second webpart?

Comment: I can't find any error in both webparts it working fine one or two times, then the page gets redirected to home page! Again it will work! This is the scenario. Is this an issue related to the connection between the two webparts ? I'm taking the filter conditions from first webpart and listing data based on that on the second page.

Comment: Check for events that may be getting triggered during execution. That's the only reason I can think of. You may have rogue event receivers in your code. Perhaps some that you used before and forgot to disable?